# Rest API - JSON object

Tags: php, json, api, rest

My company website needs php tweaking. (My previous programmer couldn't be found anymore)

I have little knowledge when it comes to js so I'm in dire need of help.

**The client e-mailed me this:**

"Basically what we need is for you to provide us with an http rest API where we will provide the tracking code and in return you will return to us a JSON object with the status of the delivery

**As an example:**

```
TRACKING CODE: ABCDEFGHIJ 
URL: http://mydomain.com/...code=ABCDEFGHIJ 
METHOD: GET 
RESPONSE: {"status":2}
```

where 2 is the code for the status shipment which is defined by:

```
1 - GOOD 
2 - BETTER 
3 - BEST"
```

How and where do I place this? What's "HTTP REST API" and "return to us a JSON object"

It's all gibberish to me! Some web guru answer me pls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably best to search and read a little before asking others to help you.

Comment: Might want to give this article a look: http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Answer (score 2):

I will not explain what HTTP REST API is because its a far big topic, better GOOGLE around.
However check this 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

API is nothing but a process where we get Platform independency.

Suppose my frontend code is written in JAVA and it's in USA.
Now my other team which is having DATABASE Access as well as Business Logic there are sitting in Russia.
How will I make them communicate?
Answer is API.

We can send data from API basically in 2 types i.e. XML and Json.
XML is traditional
Json is new and light weighted.

Your client an API which will return data in JSON format.
What they will do is 
http://apiWebAddress.com/1
1 = Id column in database
Your logics will catch this and you will return
{"status":2}

Simple, isn't? :)